# http connection does not close when doing a get against service

Tags: http, connection, http-get

When I do an HTTP GET against the following this url with this:

```
curl -HAccept:text/plain -v http://my-ip-address/myservice
```

I get the following output:

```
* About to connect() to my-ip-address port 80 (#0)
*   Trying my-ip-address...
* connected
* Connected to my-ip-address (my-ip-address) port 80 (#0)
> GET /myservice HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8x zlib/1.2.5
> Host: my-ip-address
> Accept:text/plain
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 14 Aug 2013 16:01:29 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.25 (Amazon)
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
< 
My Output

* Closing connection #0
```

When I try the following with a domain, the connection stays alive and doesn't allows my program to do subsequent gets:

```
curl -HAccept:text/plain -v http://my-domain.com/myservice


* About to connect() to my-domain port 80 (#0)
*   Trying my-ip...
* connected
* Connected to  (my-ip) port 80 (#0)
> GET /myservice/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8x zlib/1.2.5
> Host: my-domain
> Accept:text/plain
> 
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host my-domain left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http 1.1 doesn't close by default but stays open for speed.